# Flex direction column issue with wrapping on IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am having a strange issue when trying to use flex wrap with a column on IE11. The general idea is when bullet points are added at a certain height the bullet points will go onto the next line. This seems to be working for me on the browsers I have checked apart from IE11. My code is below. Is there something IE specific I need to do to get this to work?

Thank you in advance

```css
.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checkbox">
  <li>Help to Buy</li>
  <li>Part Exchange</li>
  <li>Home Scheme</li>
  <li>Chain Break</li>
  <li>Early Bird</li>
  <li>Stamp Duty</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex-wrap), there are lots of bugs with using flex in IE11. (See "Known issues" tab.) Now setting, i.e., `height:4em` makes it work, but I don't know if that's a solution for you.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, Im aware that there is a fair amount of bugs, usually I have not had too much problems with flex until today. Specifying a height has seemed to resolve the issue for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Mr Listers suggestion has worked for me. Adding a height in aswell as the max-height this now is working for me on IE11.

```css
.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checkbox">
  <li>Help to Buy</li>
  <li>Part Exchange</li>
  <li>Home Scheme</li>
  <li>Chain Break</li>
  <li>Early Bird</li>
  <li>Stamp Duty</li>
</ul>
```